# How to fix: 'Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined' of react DOM library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Yesterday i installed firebase module to my react.js application. Everything works fine. But today i found this error after compilation and display the site.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftHvA.jpg).

Could you help me with this ?

**EDIT:**

console do not display any errors of compilations

already reinstalled all packages, but didn't help

Answer (score 0):

pendingInteractionMap property or/and root object is undefined.

comment out forEach and check what is returned:

```
 console.log(root, root.pendingInteractionMap);
```

Comment: This can't help me anyway

Comment: did you try that? what values the console returns?